# Scala mutating a generic class

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following pseudo code for an increment method.

```
def increment(A: member, B: amount): B = match B {
  case: Integer => // mutate and return amount+1
  case: Float => // mutate and return amount + 1.0
}
```

I need to increment amount, an object of type B and return the same. This is fraught with issues. The above logic of incrementing the amount by matching types isn't the correct way probably, but I don't know of any other means. Even if doing something like this - how do we mutate a generic Type such as B ? Do we need something like a container class to do this ? I'm drawing a blank on all other methodologies.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
def increment [T] (a: T, b: T) (implicit T: Manifest[T], numeric: Numeric[T]): T = 
   numeric.plus (a, b)

scala> increment (7, 4)
res180: Int = 11

scala> increment (7.0, 4.0)
res181: Double = 11.0

scala> increment (7, 4.0)
res182: Double = 11.0

scala> increment (7.0, 4)
res183: Double = 11.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! However this might not fly within a generic class right ? so if I have a class[T] and try to use that generic T in this method. I am getting some error like "No TypeTag available for T" . I used TypeTag since Manifest is deprecated.

Comment: Well, I guess you have to fulfill the contract of `numeric` - do you do so and provide a plus method?